# PyQt, layout.addItem does not return a reference

Tags: python, pyqt5

I stumbled upon a problem with PyQt5.
After subclassing a horizontal box layout and populating it with three widgets (a label, a checkbox and a slider) I am adding an instance of this layout to my MainWindow application. Later in the application I need to access the values of the sliders which does not work for now. 
The instantiated single_slider whose reference is stored under self.slider_1 will be None. Therefore the attributes of this single_slider, especially the modular slider with its PyQt5 attribute slider.value() are unaccessible.
I am sure that there is something wrong with the logic, but cannot get to it.
Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Pa

```
class single_slider(QHBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        QHBoxLayout.__init__(self)
        self.label = self.addWidget(QCheckBox(), 1)
        self.cbox = self.addWidget(QLabel(), 1)
        self.slider = self.addWidget(QSlider(orientation=Qt.Horizontal), 5)

class MyApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.slider_1 = self.grid.addItem(single_slider())
        print(self.slider_1)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.grid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyApp()
    win.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addItem()` method does not return any value, nor does the `addWidget()` method, what you have to do is create the object before and then assign them with those methods:

```
class single_slider(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        QHBoxLayout.__init__(self)
        self.cbox = QCheckBox()
        self.label = QLabel("label")
        self.slider = QSlider(orientation=Qt.Horizontal)

        self.addWidget(self.cbox)
        self.addWidget(self.label)
        self.addWidget(self.slider, 5)

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.slider_1 = single_slider()
        self.grid.addItem(self.slider_1)
        self.slider_1.slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: print(val))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.grid)
```